# JNI for C++ class UnsatisfieldLinkError

Tags: c++, c++11, java-native-interface

Hy guys!

I know there is too many topics about JNI here but, I am newbie whit JNI, so i decide to write a new one.

I am trying to write a JNI to access some C++ class in Java layer, but im getting the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: arm.test.lib.FooClass.init(I)V
    at arm.test.lib.FooClass.init(Native Method)
    at arm.test.lib.FooClass.<init>(FooClass.java:13)
    at arm.test.app.Main.main(Main.java:9)
<end of output>
```

I have the following project tree

`source
├── build  
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── foo
|   ├── src
|   |   ├── foo.cpp
|   |   └── foo.h
|   ├── include
|   |   └── foo.h -> ../src/foo.h
|   └── CMakeLists.txt
└── java-jni
    ├── c
    ├── CMakeLists.txt
    │   └── jni_wrapper.cpp
    └── java
        └── src
            └── arm
                └── test
                    ├── app
                    │   └── Main.java
                    └── lib
                        └── FooClass.java`

The CMakeLists.txt from source folder:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project(java-cpp)

include_directories(foo)

option(BUILD_TESTS "Build the test suite (requires foo)" ON)
if(BUILD_TESTS)
    enable_testing()
endif()

add_subdirectory(foo)
add_subdirectory(java-jni)
```

The CMakeLists.txt from foo folder:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project(foo)

add_compile_options(-std=c++11)

set(PROJECT_PATH    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
set(SRCS_PATH       "${PROJECT_PATH}/src")
set(CPPLIB_INCLUDE_DIR  "${PROJECT_PATH}/include" CACHE INTERNAL "foo include directories") 

include_directories(${CPPLIB_INCLUDE_DIR})

file(GLOB SRCS "${SRCS_PATH}/*.cpp" "${SRCS_PATH}/*.h")

add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} SHARED ${SRCS})
```

Foo is a simple class, constructor and some functions...

## foo.h

```
#ifndef CLASS_H
#define CLASS_H

class Foo {

private:
    int m_nb;

public:
    Foo(int &n_nb);
    int getValue() const;
    void increment();

};
```

## foo.cpp

```
#include <iostream>

#include "foo.h"


    Foo::Foo(int &n_nb) :m_nb(n_nb)
    {
        std::cout << n_nb << std::endl;
    }

    int Foo::getValue() const 
    {
        return this->m_nb;
    }

    void Foo::increment()
    {
        this->m_nb++;
    }
```

And the CMakeLists.txt from java-jni

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

# REQUIRED JAVA
FIND_PACKAGE(Java COMPONENTS Development)
INCLUDE(UseJava)
SET(CMAKE_JAVA_COMPILE_FLAGS "-source" "1.8" "-target" "1.8")

SET(JAVA_SOURCE_FILES 
arm/test/app/Main.java 
arm/test/lib/FooClass.java)


# Build Java classes
FILE(MAKE_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/java/bin")
SET(class_files)
FOREACH(_java_file ${JAVA_SOURCE_FILES})
    # _java_file: relative file name
    # _class_file: relative class name
    STRING(REGEX REPLACE "\\.java$"
       ".class" _class_file
           "${_java_file}")
    ADD_CUSTOM_COMMAND(
        OUTPUT "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/java/bin/${_class_file}"
        COMMAND
            ${Java_JAVAC_EXECUTABLE}
            ${CMAKE_JAVA_COMPILE_FLAGS}
            -sourcepath "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/java/src"
            -d "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/java/bin"
            "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/java/src/${_java_file}"
        DEPENDS "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/java/src/${_java_file}")
    LIST(APPEND class_files "java/bin/${_class_file}")
ENDFOREACH()

ADD_CUSTOM_TARGET(JavaJNIClasses ALL DEPENDS ${class_files})

# Make the JNI header file
ADD_CUSTOM_COMMAND(
    OUTPUT "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/include/FooClass_jni.h"
    COMMAND
        ${Java_JAVAH_EXECUTABLE}
        -o "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/include/FooClass_jni.h"
        -classpath "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/java/bin"
        arm.test.lib.FooClass
    DEPENDS "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/java/bin/arm/test/lib/FooClass.class")
ADD_CUSTOM_TARGET(JavaJNIHeaders ALL DEPENDS "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/include/FooClass_jni.h")

# Require JNI
FIND_PACKAGE(JNI REQUIRED)

# Builds the JNI wrapper
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES("${CPPLIB_INCLUDE_DIR}"
                   "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/include"
                    ${JNI_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

ADD_LIBRARY(foo_jni SHARED c/jni_wrapper.cpp)

link_directories("${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/foo")

SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES(
    foo_jni PROPERTIES
    LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}"
    LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_DEBUG "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}"
    LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}"
    RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}"
    RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_DEBUG "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}"
    RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}")

TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(foo_jni foo)

ADD_DEPENDENCIES(foo_jni JavaJNIHeaders)

# Testing
IF(BUILD_TESTS)
    FIND_PACKAGE(Java COMPONENTS Runtime)
    ADD_TEST(
        NAME run-jni
        COMMAND
            "${Java_JAVA_EXECUTABLE}"
            -cp java-jni/java/bin
            -Djava.library.path=${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}
            arm.test.app.Main
        WORKING_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}")
ENDIF()
```

Inside C path is the wrapper C to java.

```
#include  "foo.h"

#include "FooClass_jni.h"

static jfieldID _get_self_id(JNIEnv *env, jobject thisObj)
{
    static int init = 0;
    static jfieldID fidSelfPtr;
    if(!init)
    {
        jclass thisClass = env->GetObjectClass(thisObj);
        fidSelfPtr = env->GetFieldID(thisClass, "self_ptr", "J");
    }
    return fidSelfPtr;
}
static Foo *_get_self(JNIEnv *env, jobject thisObj)
{
    jlong selfPtr = env->GetLongField(thisObj, _get_self_id(env, thisObj));
    return *(Foo**)&selfPtr;
}

static void _set_self(JNIEnv *env, jobject thisObj, Foo *self)
{
    jlong selfPtr = *(jlong*)&self;
    env->SetLongField(thisObj, _get_self_id(env, thisObj), selfPtr);
}


extern "C" JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_arm_test_lib_Foo_init(JNIEnv *env, jobject thisObj, jint nb)
{
    Foo *self = new Foo(nb);
    _set_self(env, thisObj, self);
}

extern "C" JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_arm_test_lib_Foo_getValue(JNIEnv *env, jobject thisObj)
{
    Foo *self = _get_self(env, thisObj);
    return self->getValue();
}

extern "C" JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_arm_test_lib_Foo_increment(JNIEnv *env, jobject thisObj)
{
    Foo *self = _get_self(env, thisObj);
    self->increment();
}

extern "C" JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_arm_test_lib_Foo_finalize(JNIEnv *env, jobject thisObj)
{
    Foo *self = _get_self(env, thisObj);
    if(self != NULL)
    {
        delete self;
        _set_self(env, thisObj, NULL);
    }
}
```

When i ran the cmake file inside java-jni the javah generate to my this file.

```
/* DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - it is machine generated */
#include <jni.h>
/* Header for class arm_test_lib_FooClass */

#ifndef _Included_arm_test_lib_FooClass
#define _Included_arm_test_lib_FooClass
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
/*
 * Class:     arm_test_lib_FooClass
 * Method:    init
 * Signature: (I)V
 */
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_arm_test_lib_FooClass_init
  (JNIEnv *, jobject, jint);

/*
 * Class:     arm_test_lib_FooClass
 * Method:    getValue
 * Signature: ()I
 */
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_arm_test_lib_FooClass_getValue
  (JNIEnv *, jobject);

/*
 * Class:     arm_test_lib_FooClass
 * Method:    increment
 * Signature: ()V
 */
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_arm_test_lib_FooClass_increment
  (JNIEnv *, jobject);

/*
 * Class:     arm_test_lib_FooClass
 * Method:    finalize
 * Signature: ()V
 */
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_arm_test_lib_FooClass_finalize
  (JNIEnv *, jobject);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif
```

finaly i got the FooClass.java

```
package arm.test.lib;

public class FooClass{

    static {
        System.loadLibrary("foo_jni");
    }

    private long self_ptr;

    public FooClass(int nb)
    {
        init(nb);
    }

    private native void init(int nb);

    public native int getValue();

    public native void increment();

    protected native void finalize();

}
```

the code is available in:

https://github.com/eduardoaugustojulio/java-cpp-study

Best regards.

Comment: The code must be available *here.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your **jni_wrapper.cpp** is written for Java class **Foo**, but you try to use it from class **FooClass**.

Comment: Yeah! You are right, thank you! I re-named the functions `Java_arm_test_lib_Foo` to `Java_arm_test_lib_FooClass` and worked.

Comment: If you accept the answer, JNI will work even better ;)